# Unable to redirect from Drupal to PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-7, paypal-sandbox

I'm totally new to Drupal. I created a form in Drupal using pure HTML when the user clicks on pay I call a PHP file just to get some database information subsequently this PHP redirects to another PHP that puts the PayPal payment together.

For some reason the PayPal payment PHP does not redirect to PayPal when it is called from under Drupal. My layers are as follows:

https://example.com/test/?q=node/11 --> call savedatatoDB.php --> call paypalpreparepayment.php --> redirect to paypal

If I call the PayPal payment PHP from the browser directly like this:
https://example.com/test/paypal/restapi/sample/payments/PaymentPP.php?samount=0.005&sprice=123.45&description=products&sqty=100

it works! I thought the problem could be an output before header() but it is not the case.

I wrote a line to write to a log file right before the redirect like this:

```
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$log = "{$today} ready to redirect {$sale_description}, {$sale_amount}, {$sale_quantity}, {$sale_price}\n";
//Save string to log, use FILE_APPEND to append.
file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
header("Location: $redirectUrl");
exit;
```

And the log shows that I'm getting that far but no redirect! but again if I call that PHP directly from the browser then I see PayPal asking me to authorize.

So when I'm under Drupal UI, I'm wondering if Drupal could be blocking the redirect somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Drupal.org which makes sense.

here is the link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2365503#comment-9295613

> [Jaypan](https://www.drupal.org/u/jaypan) commented about 11 hours ago
>
> The problem is that your redirect is on the server side, but you are
>   triggering it with JavaScript. If the trigger is in your JS, then the
>   redirect also needs to happen in the JS. If the trigger is non-JS
>   (submits to the server), then your redirect can be on the server side.